# change value into array on PG with RubyOnRails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I've try to change one value into and array on PG on RubyOnRails but it doesn't work, somebody know some gem or some trick for do that ?

I've try to update the value on this way ->

```
new_value = [2,5,7]

(0..2).each do |index|
Table.update(:key[index] => new_value[index])
end
```

Comment: Presumably `key` is an array column. Are you trying to replace the whole array? Just the first three (or `new_value.count`) elements?

Comment: I've try to change all the valute and I've try to change just one of that, and If I want use .count I'll need to change (0..2) to (0...new_value.count) "is the same thing i think.

Answer (score 0):

This is really not a PG issue. It is purely a ruby one. Try using `map`. Here is an example in IRB...

`2.2.3 :001 > new_value = [2,5,7]
 => [2, 5, 7]
2.2.3 :002 > new_value.map do |index|
2.2.3 :003 >     index = index + 1
2.2.3 :004?>   end
 => [3, 6, 8]`